# encrypted server, decrypted user for web app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, security, spring-security

I have a spring mvc app using MySQL on a remote Linux server with tomcat.  The web host separates the app into a database server and an application server.  I can encrypt the MySQL database so that the contents of the database server are useless to hackers or to a malicious employee of the hosting company.  But that would leave the contents of the application server unencrypted and thus vulnerable to anyone with administrator privileges on the application server, so that the war file and the data flowing between the application server and users could be compromised.  Is there some way that I can encrypt not only everything on the application server, but also all the content sent between the server and end users, so that the end users would only see jibberish in their web browsers unless they have a key to decrypt it?

I am envisioning each authorized user having a 256 bit encryption key on their computer.  Their key would not only decrypt everything they receive from the server, but would also encrypt everything they send to the server for storage in the database.  I would like this to work in a web browser, and for me to only have to write a minimal amount of client side code.  What tools or libraries are available for this sort of thing?

I use java, spring, MySQL, and related technologies, but can learn other things.

Comment: Aren't you better off using SSL to encrypt data flowing from one end to another? On a side note. Your question seems a bit paranoid. No offense :)

Comment: @Bart I was gonna wrap it all in SSL also.  But SSL does not protect the code and the unencrypted data from someone who has administrative privileges on the application server.  For example, an employee of the web hosting company.

Comment: If someone has administrative privileges on the server it's very hard to protect your data. If you want to be absolutely safe you should host the application yourself on your own hardware.

Comment: @Bart Hosting it myself is not an option for this app.  But If my code is obfuscated, and if all data retains the encryption from the database (perhaps even with a second layer of encryption) until it gets to the end user, then the server administrator will only see encrypted data and code.  My question is about some way of encrypting/decrypting at the client side.

Comment: @Bart The app will be on a dedicated server and will use ssl.  I will be the only one with administrator privileges.  But the web hosting company performs automated maintenance of such servers and has access in that way.  One of their employees could thus get their credentials and breach the server.  My question is about how to encrypt/decrypt at the client side so that nothing on the server is usable even if a rogue employee gets to it.  I doubt I am the only one with this requirement.

Comment: If the rogue employee is the biggest attack vector you should prevent the employee from going into your machine. It's a horrible idea to encrypt/decrypt on the client as well. It would only be possible with browser plugins since the server response is encrypted. So you would write plugins for all major browsers as well if you want a wide coverage. You will need to find a balance in the security risk you can accept and the cost that is coming with it. Cost in development time that is.

Comment: @Bart Browser plugin.  Thank you for that idea.  The employee would not be under our control because the web host would employ the potentially harmful person.  The number of users for this app is small.  We can require all users to have the same browser.  I wonder if a plugin like this has already been developed and might be available for use?